# How can I include information to my android application post compilation?

Tags: android, dynamic, java-me, j2mepolish

Currently I supply a user with a URL to click on to download my j2me application.  This URL includes their user id as a parameter, a servlet takes this information and dynamically creates a jad file that includes this user id , thus making the user id available to the j2me app.

However, I am now using j2me polish to compile my program and thus have the compiled .apk for this same program.  However, I cannot work out how to make this information accessible to the the compiled program as there is no jad / jar mechanism.  The information is only available at the time of download.

Any suggestions gratefully received!  (is this even possible in an android application?)

Thanks,

CJ

p.s. I have to assume complete illiteracy from the users point of view, i.e. I cannot ask them to first install other programs etc, it needs to be a simple "click on the link" -> "get the app" sort of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.apk` format is based on the `.jar` format so is just a ZIP file meaning you can open it with anything that processes ZIP files.

Files which are in the `assets` folder of your application aren't altered by the `.apk` build process so it should be possible to store the URL in a text file in `assets` and then read it using [`AssetManager.open()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#open(java.lang.String)).  Your server would have to open the `.apk` and update the text file in `assets` before offering it for download.

However, a complication is that [all Android applications must be signed](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/publishing/app-signing.html) or they will not install.  This is true even if you're not distributing your application via the Market.  So as well as updating the `.apk` file your server would have to re-sign it using something like `keytool`.